# How to use a trained model on different inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I implemented a relatively straightforward logistic regression function. I save all the necessary variables such as weights, bias, x, y, etc. and then I run the training algorithm...

```
# launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    # training cycle
    for epoch in range(FLAGS.training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/FLAGS.batch_size)
        # loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)

            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})

            # compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch + 1) % FLAGS.display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))

    save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
```

The model is saved and the `prediction` and `accuracy` of the trained model is displayed...

```
# list of booleans to determine the correct predictions
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
print(correct_prediction.eval({x:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.labels}))

# calculate total accuracy
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

This is all fine and dandy. However, now I want to be able to predict any given image using the trained model. For example, I want to feed it picture of say `7` and see what it predicts it to be.

I have another module that restores the model. First we load the variables...

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# tf Graph Input
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])  # mnist data image of shape 28*28=784
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])  # 0-9 digits recognition => 10 classes

# set model weights
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

# construct model
pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)  # Softmax

# minimize error using cross entropy
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(pred), reduction_indices=1))
# Gradient Descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    save.restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
```

This is good. Now I want to compare one image to the model and get a prediction. In this example, I take the first image from the test dataset `mnist.test.images[0]` and I attempt to compare it to the model.

```
classification = sess.run(tf.argmax(pred, 1), feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[0]})
print(classification)
```

I know this will not work. I get the error...

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (784,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 784)'

I am at a loss for ideas. This question is rather long, if a straightforward answer is not possible, some guidance as to the steps I may take to do this is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to reshape your image array from (784,) to (1,784). Because 784 is the features in single features and estimator requires array with shape `(n_samples, n_features)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input placeholder must be of size `(?, 784)`, the question mark meaning variable size which is probably the batch size. You are feeding an input of size `(784,)` which does not work as the error message states.

In your case, during prediction time, the batch size is just 1, so the following should work:

```
import numpy as np
...
x_in = np.expand_dims(mnist.test.images[0], axis=0)
classification = sess.run(tf.argmax(pred, 1), feed_dict={x:x_in})
```

Assuming that the input image is available as a numpy array. If it is already a tensor, the corresponding function is `tf.expand_dims(..)`.